# Can we implement an object in more than one source file?

Tags: delphi, oop

I have a `Unit1.pas` (for example) where I have a `TService` with a `TIdTCPServer` and a `TIdUDPServer` components dropped in, but I would like to have the event methods implemented in different files, like `UDP.pas` and `TCP.pas`. Is it possible if they are part of TService? How?

Comment: Wouldn't that be a serious blow to readability to have methods scattered across different units?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A class cannot be implemented across multiple units. However, event handlers can be implemented anywhere.

Comment: Right, I used that approach before, and I completely ignored that possibility in this project (lack of coffee I guess) :-0

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid you cannot implement it in a different *unit* because a compiled unit (.dcu) must contain implementation of all methods that are declared in its interface.

But it's possible to write some parts of the implementation in separate files and then include them (with the `{$I` directive) into the main unit.

E.g. in implementation section of your Unit1.pas you add lines

```
{$I TCP.pas}
{$I UDP.pas}
```

and then you implement some methods in the TCP.pas and UDP.pas (without any `unit` or `interface` or `implementation` keywords of course), just as if you were writing inside the `implementation` part of Unit1.pas.
Of course all the methods (both 'local' and 'included') must be declared in the interface sections of Unit1.pas.

Usually the files to be included have an extension `.inc`.

Probably you might review your design so that you don't have logically independent blocks being all in one class. Maybe separating the service logic from the TCP and UDP logic (different classes and therefore different units) would lead to more elegant design.

Comment: Very useful information, but is the IDE going to think about these files as a complement of the main unit when executing the Code Editor features like showing undeclared identifiers and auto-completion?

Comment: At least in Delphi 6 the IDE ignores the included files when auto-completing etc., but debugger goes into them. I suppose the same goes for XE2, although I cannot verify it right now.

Comment: So - yes, the 'include' feature is not a nice way to split code into separate files.

Comment: @EASI: the IDE of the newer versions will show errors, hints, etc. in include files too. Not sure about older versions like D6.